# ATMEGA328P ADSC ADC Start Conversion Clock Cycles, Multi Channel Free Running ADC

Tags: adc

Reference [Datasheet](http://www.jdnd.co.uk/Products/47/Files/ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) page 218

• Bit 6 – ADSC: ADC Start Conversion
In single conversion mode, write this bit to one to start each conversion. In free running mode, write this bit to one to start the first conversion. The first conversion after ADSC has been written after the ADC has been enabled, or if ADSC is written at the same time as the ADC is enabled, will take 25 ADC clock cycles instead of the normal 13. This first conversion performs initialization of the ADC.

25 ADC clock cycles instead of the normal 13

does this mean that changing bit 6 will take 25 or 13 ADC clock cycles to to return before then executing the next instruction?

or that it will return immediately but the ADC will not start for 25 or 13 ADC clock cycles?

Working Code In Question, if it helps

```
volatile uint8_t AnalogActivePinIndex = 0;
volatile uint8_t AnalogActivePins[3] =
{
    outputVoltagePin.Pin,
    inputVoltagePin.Pin,
    ampsIn_Pin.Pin
};
void AnalogInit()
{
    // clear ADLAR in ADMUX (0x7C) to right-adjust the result
    // ADCL will contain lower 8 bits, ADCH upper 2 (in last two bits)
    ADMUX &= 0b11011111;

    // Set REFS1..0 in ADMUX (0x7C) to change reference voltage to the proper source (01)
    ADMUX |= 0b01000000;

    // Clear MUX3..0 in ADMUX (0x7C) in preparation for setting the analog input
    ADMUX &= 0b11110000;

    // Set MUX3..0 in ADMUX (0x7C) to read from selected input pin
    // Do not set above 15! You will overrun other parts of ADMUX. 
    // A full list of possible inputs is available in Table 24-4 of the ATMega328 datasheet
    ADMUX |= AnalogActivePins[AnalogActivePinIndex];
    
    // Set ADEN in ADCSRA (0x7A) to enable the ADC.
    // Note, this instruction takes 12 ADC clocks to execute
    ADCSRA |= 0b10000000;

    // Set ADATE in ADCSRA (0x7A) to enable auto-triggering.
    ADCSRA |= 0b00100000;

    // Clear ADTS2..0 in ADCSRB (0x7B) to set trigger mode to free running.
    // This means that as soon as an ADC has finished, the next will be immediately started.
    //ADCSRB &= 0b11111000;

    // Set the Prescaler to 128 (16000KHz/128 = 125KHz)
    // Above 200KHz 10-bit results are not reliable.
    ADCSRA |= 0b00000111;

    // Set ADIE in ADCSRA (0x7A) to enable the ADC interrupt.
    // Without this, the internal interrupt will not trigger.
    ADCSRA |= 0b00001000;

    // Enable global interrupts
    // AVR macro included in <avr/interrupts.h>, which the Arduino IDE supplies by default.
    sei();

    // Set ADSC in ADCSRA (0x7A) to start the ADC conversion
    ADCSRA |= 0b01000000;
}
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    if (AnalogActivePins[AnalogActivePinIndex] == inputVoltagePin.Pin)
    {
        uint32_t voltage1 = ((uint32_t)(ADCL | (ADCH << 8)) * vdMaxInput1) / 1024;
        inputVoltageAverage.Update(voltage1);
        voltage1 = inputVoltageAverage.GetValue();
        inputVoltage1 = (uint16_t)voltage1;
    }
    else if (AnalogActivePins[AnalogActivePinIndex] == outputVoltagePin.Pin)
    {
        uint32_t voltage1 = ((uint32_t)(ADCL | (ADCH << 8)) * vdMaxOutput1) / 1024;
        outputVoltageAverage.Update(voltage1);
        voltage1 = outputVoltageAverage.GetValue();
        outputVoltage1 = (uint16_t)voltage1;
    }
    else if (AnalogActivePins[AnalogActivePinIndex] == ampsIn_Pin.Pin)
    {
        uint32_t ampsInValue = ADCL | (ADCH << 8);
        ampsInAverage.Update(ampsInValue);
        ampsInValue = ampsInAverage.GetValue();
        if (ampsInValue >= 511)
        {
            float ampsIn = (float)(ampsInValue - 511) / 17.5f;
            ampsIn1 = (uint16_t)(ampsIn * 10.0f);
        }
        else { ampsIn1 = 0; }
    }
    
    if (AnalogActivePinIndex >= 2)
    {
        AnalogActivePinIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        AnalogActivePinIndex++;
    }
    
    // disbale ADC
    ADCSRA = (ADCSRA & ~0b10000000);
    
    // select new channel
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & ~0b00001111) | (AnalogActivePins[AnalogActivePinIndex] & 0b00001111);

    // re-enable ADC
    ADCSRA |= 0b10000000;
    
    UpdatePWM();
    
    // Set ADSC in ADCSRA to start another ADC conversion, Not needed if free-running mode is enabled.
    ADCSRA |= 0b01000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register writes are just that, the CPU writing blindly into memory.  They are non-blocking.  The cycle count concerns only operation of the ADC itself.

Moreover, the cycles are the ADC clock cycles, i.e. main clock divided by ADC prescaler.

If you look at the assembly output, you will see the writes take several instructions, totaling maybe up to 6 CPU cycles (depending on which type of instruction is suitable for the expression, and what the compiler chose to emit for it).

Comment: thanks, for clarity, your saying the answer is "that it will return immediately but the ADC will not start for 25 or 13 ADC clock cycles?"

Comment: Yes, the ADC takes 25 (first time since enable) or 13 (subsequent) of its cycles.